# Re adding broken pads

Tags: repair, pad

I'm doing 2 repairs and currently the pads are missing. I have jumper wire and I try to solder it on with flux but the tinned copper wire doesn't stick too the surface. I've been trying for 4 days now and can't seem to get it. I'm making sure the tip is clean, I'm tinning it, it seems like it just won't stick. Any tips?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjnuD.jpg]

Comment: If the pads are missing, you need to scrap away some soldermask and solder to the traces that attach to those pads.

Comment: Now that I look at the image.... Unless this is something you really need that cost you millions, just get a new one or give up on it. That's beyond any reasonable repair.

Comment: Yes I figured on that one. Was just going to get a japanese board and swap everything so it's in English

Comment: You've pulled the pads off the board. No amount of flux will make wires stick to the bare PCB substrate, and it wouldn't help you even if it did.

Comment: What size is the package?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to put an IC on there... Yeah that's going to be tough. You could technically make a small strand of solder coming from the copper trace and tack it onto the package. This might be a substitute for a pad. Soldering copper traces can be a real pain in the butt.

Answer (score 1):

The pads are gone, they need to be re-built.

if you can figure out where they connected you can solder new wire to replace the missing copper (need to scrape away some of the green) and then glue the wire down
with heat-proof glue, and then solder the chip to the new wires and the existing pads.